# How can I transfer my injustice from android to iPad

Tags: ios

I have an account on android with all of stuff - regime superman arkham origins batman and death stroke. I recently got an iPad mini for my birthday, and I would like to put my data from android to my iPad.

Answer (score 1):

If Injustice on iPad doesn't have a menu item to do this, and it doesn't sync game saves via the internet (very few games do this in a cross-platform way), then you can't do it. It's possible to extract the save games from Injustice on Android if your phone is rooted, but iOS doesn't have this feature, so there'd be no way to put the save file into your iPad.